# Minecraft server (aws/linux) discord webhook error

Tags: systemd, python, minecraft

I have a Minecraft server running on an EC2 Instance (AWS), which runs a Linux (CentOS). I altered the `minecraft.service` system process to

```ini
ExecStart=python3 run_server.py
```

This python script pulls a `run.json` file, which fills in server jar name, webhook URL, role ID, and jvm args. This is what it looks like:

```json
{
  "server_jar":"server.jar",
  "jvm_args":"-Xms1G -Xmx4G",
  "webhook_url":"your_url_here",
  "role_id":"your_role_here"
}
```

When I run `sudo systemctl start minecraft` followed by `sudo systemctl status minecraft` I get this error:

```
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:  
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
 self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 1953, in _execute_child
 raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)  
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'java -Xmx3G -Xms3G -jar server.jar nogui'
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without knowing the contents of `start_server.py` and the `.service` file.

Answer (score 0):

While it would help to see more of the python code, I have a hunch that you get this error because it's trying to run that big string with spaces as a single command name. Instead, you have to pass in a list.

**Incorrect:**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen('java -Xmx3G -Xms3G -jar server.jar nogui', stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

**Correct:**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen(
    ['java', '-Xmx3G', '-Xms3G', '-jar', 'server.jar', 'nogui'],
    stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE
)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

See how it broke apart the long string into different sub-parts and passed as a list?

This answer could help more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605498/how-to-use-subprocess-popen-python

Comment: This is more of a python code issue though, so might be good to ask on StackOverflow. And you'll need to modify the python code to fix it.